# Android accelerometer detects only two dimensions changes

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I'm learning about accelerometer in android. I'm getting new values when tilting the phone around the green and the blue arraw, but not the red one!

[image]

That's actually my problem. And here's the code I'm using:

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;

...........

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

...........

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the red one, the only change is the acceleration upward and downward. This acceleration is dominated by gravity, so there is only a slight change in value.

Comment: Thanks. But I think there must be a way to measure rotation around that axis. Mustn't there?

Comment: Yes, it is the pitch or roll depending on the phone orientation. If you think of it as the angle between the screen and world xy plane then it is arcos(event.values[2]).